# object.stringValue from QR code is not being parsed to a Variable in a different class

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code to scan QR code from my app but I want the string that is obtained from the QR code: `object.stringValue` to be passed into a variable of my choice.

I searched a lot about this specific topic on log-ing in with QR code or how to parse data from the `object.stringValue` to variables but nothing came up.

This function below is in class `QRCodeViewController`

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0
    {
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController()
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Vazhdo", style: .default, handler: {_ in
                    
                    let theID = object.stringValue
                    
                    let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
                    viewController.id = theID!
                
                    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
                    controller?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
                    controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
      
                }))
                    
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want that `object.stringValue` to be parsed here on the `MonitorimiViewController` which is the other class

```
var id: String = ""
```

Comment: I guess: `MonitorimiViewController()` you are creating a whole new instance of `MonitorimiViewController`, and I don't think that's the one you are seeing latter on screen. Is that the case? You are lacking informations, it's not clear how you test, and what's working or not.

Comment: @Larme hey thanks for your reply , MonitorimiViewController() is the other class that has the var ID which i want the data to be parsed to it from the object.stringValue in this case theID. Basically parse from theID to ID from A class to B class

Comment: You need to edit your question with more info. Where is set the `id`, where doo you read it doesn't work. Which are the methods, in which classes, etc. But since I still guess it's an instance problem, it's like have `let first = "first"`, and let second = String()` and you keep using `second`, they are different. Here, `viewController` is not the one you think it is. `first` is set, but `second` is the one you use...

Comment: @Larme here ill update my question so it can be more clear

Comment: Why you didn't try to implement delegate to get the scanned data on your specific. view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the string to `MonitorimiViewController` but you are opening `tabBarController`.

```
let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
viewController.id = theID!
                
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
controller?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Try to set the string value to `tabBarController`.

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
controller?.id = theID!
controller?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After this, you need to set the `id` value in the tab bar controller when you set the view controller.

In `MonitorimiViewController` you can assign the value as

```
let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
viewController.id = id
```