# How to create and Implement basic login with QRcode?

Tags: ios, swift

So for this project I am in I need to implement a login using QR code, but I am new to swift and I don't know how

Right now I am implementing the QR code which scans and gets a string shown, I want that string to be placed into the API ID variable which gets the list of cars in my case from the API call

This is the QRCodeViewController() class, a function which gets the string from the scan:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0
    {
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController()
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Vazhdo", style: .default, handler: {_ in
                    
                    let idfromQR = object.stringValue
                    let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
                    viewController.id = idfromQR!
                    
                    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
                    controller?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
                    controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
  
            }))
                
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now I want that object. StringValue that comes from the QR scanned to be passed into the MonitorimiViewController() which is another class which hold the ID value that needs to get from the object. StringValue but I am struggling to pass that value because it isn't being parsed, I tried all I know but all failed to be parsed.

This is the MonitorimiViewController() class
So the object.stringValue must be passed in this `var id: String = "object.stringValue"`

```
var id: String = "0E79C6205FD04F8994B13F5255B7FB05"
```

Comment: `MonitorimiViewController` inside the tab bar ?

Comment: Please don't post the same question over and over. You received answers and comments, please respond to them before asking the same question again [object.stringValue from QR code is not being parsed to a Variable in a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783836/object-stringvalue-from-qr-code-is-not-being-parsed-to-a-variable-in-a-different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following lines of code:

```
let idfromQR = object.stringValue
let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
viewController.id = idfromQR!
                
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController")
                
controller?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You are assigning the qr code response to a view controller that is never getting presented. So you should instead assign it to one of the tabbar controller's view controllers.

Replace the code above with this code to solve your problem:

```
guard let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as? UITabBarController else {
   // Something wrong with your identifier
   return
}

(tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as? MonitorimiViewController)?.id = idfromQR!           
tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This assumes that MonitorimiViewController is the first index view controller in your tab bar controller, if it is not just change the 0 index to another number.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've posted a near identical answer to mine ~24 hours later?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new viewController, passing the QR code value into it, then you do nothing with the viewController and it falls out of memory.

```
let idfromQR = object.stringValue
let viewController = MonitorimiViewController()
viewController.id = idfromQR
```

You don't do anything with `viewController` after this point. You create a tabBarController from a storyboard, which creates new copies of these classes and open those new copies.

You would need to do something like this instead:

```
guard let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as? UITabBarController,
      let monitorController = controller.viewControllers.first as? MonitorimiViewController else {
    return
}

monitorController.id = idfromQR

self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What i'm doing here is:

- Getting the tabBarController from the storyboard
- Getting one of the viewControllers it manages (i'm grabbing the
  first, I don't know what index yours is).
- Checking that they can all be cast to the correct types.
- Passing the value into the `MonitorimiViewController` being used by the tabBar
- Presenting the tabBar with the updated `MonitorimiViewController`

Please also make sure to use `if let xxx` or `guard let xxx` statements and avoid force unwrapping (e.g. `idfromQR!`) at all costs. It will crash your app if a problem occurs

Comment: Hey Simon thanks a lot for your answer , I tried your code and its very good but its not presenting the controller its just stuck at the qr code scanning

Comment: @Lis1 its most likely getting caught by the `guard` statement, put a print out above the `return` to verify it. Did you change it to the correct viewController index like I mentioned? (e.g. `controller.viewControllers.first` needs to point to where-ever your `MonitorimiViewController` is being used)

Comment: Hey simon i didnt change the controller index as I have no clue what that index is or where to find it in MonitorimiViewController :( , but I am learning day by day and if you could help on this one It would be great since I am stuck with this qr thing for like days... to be honest

Comment: @Lis1 ok in future if someone mentions you need to change something, don't ignore it and say the code didn't work, as them what this means. You are creating a controller from a storyboard with the id `tabBarController` I have assumed that is a `UITabBarController`, is that correct? If so, this controller *manages* a number of other viewControllers. So for example `controller.viewControlers[0]` might be your homepage, `controller.viewControlers[1]` might be your monitor page, `controller.viewControlers[2]` might be your settings and so on. You've not provided any details about this, so I ...

Comment: can't tell you what index to use. You need to update that bit yourself. ViewControllers are not singletons, you need to get a reference to the class thats on the screen

Comment: Ohh okay okay i totally get it now mate, Thanks a lot man and i didnt say its not working? , also I have 3 controllers ill show a pic below https://ibb.co/gF6JBBt

Comment: also this is my code now https://ibb.co/512cb60 , btw the index as first means thats okay since monitorimiViewController is the first one so the problem must be somewere else, I just dont know where

Comment: @Lis1 people are unlikely to click odd looking links and download someone else's code. You need to edit your question and add any images or extra code to the original question. Regarding trying to figure out whats wrong here, you need to debug it. If you are new to Xcode and find the debugger itself complicated, you can simply put some console prints everywhere. As I mentioned in a previous comment, put one inside the guard and see does it reach there, copy paste out the variables and see are you getting the controller from the storyboard, can you cast it, how many viewControllers does it have

Comment: @Lis1 you've marked the other identical answer as accepted, but told me my answer doesn't work. Something seems odd here